# GitHub Desktop:Authentication failed.You may not have permission to access the repository

Tags: windows, git, windows-10

Team,

My github desktop was working correctly. I am able to perform all the operations like Commit, Pull, Push. Today I am trying to push my code, observe below error :

> Authentication failed. You may not have permission to access the
>   repository or the repository may have been archived. Open options and
>   verify that you're signed in with an account that has permission to
>   access this repository.

**My environment :**

- Windows : 10
- GitHub Desktop : 1.6.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Step for fix issue:

1. Remove repo from GitHub Desktop
2. Logout from your github account [File > Options]
3. File > Add Local Repository
4. **Repository > Repository Settings and change to https URL** [Important tweek]

It started working back for me.

Comment: Thank you. It worked for me too but what's the reason ?

Comment: Just want to thank you for this suggestion, I was absolutely stuck trying to add a existing repo and getting this error, I finally just tried adding the repo instead of getting it again and it worked to resolve the issue.